# Get current S3 object version with AWS CLI without downloading the object body itself

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is there an AWS CLI command to get the current version of an S3 object without downloading the object itself?

The best I've come up with downloads the first byte of the object and writes it to `/dev/null`:

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket mybucket --key myfile --range bytes=0-0 /dev/null | jq '.VersionId'
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command shown below:

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket mybucket --prefix myfile.css
```

Here's the output looks like.

```
{
    "Versions": [
        {
            "ETag": "\"e4ac40b47c1e1b9269450424f4b72cc1\"",
            "Size": 3359,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            "Key": "myfile.css",
            "VersionId": "Nz7zrGFB_mdYp8Lx7g0rKkDeD3JHUv9f",
            "IsLatest": true,
            "LastModified": "2020-12-08T14:05:40+00:00",
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": "info",
                "ID": "07d06a23da0fa42d662773a9f6ca9f68d3109579d5937630fbe027cc77c36136"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please refer to details [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/list-object-versions.html).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!  The AWS CLI documentation doesn't specify the ordering of `Versions`, so `--no-paginate` might be needed to find the current version in a single call.